# Programmatically retrieve returncode from ant-task

Tags: java, ant

Had a problem with retrieving returncode programmatically...following files. (did cut out some company-specific things). I got 2 files, one general file with a java-task in it and a specific file, which defines sime properties and a ant-task.

How can i get the build.rc in my executing java-test? The echo-message at the end of the file delivers the actual return-code, but the p.getProperty("build.rc") returns null.

**specific.build.xml**

```
<project basedir="../../../.." name="run-joblauncher">
     <property name="prop1" value="valProp1" />
     <ant antfile="./dev/script/general.xml" dir="${basedir}" target="RUN-MYCLASS" inheritAll="true"/>
</project>
```

**general.xml**

```
<project basedir="../../../.." default="RUN-MYCLASS" name="run-specifictest"> <target name="RUN-MYCLASS"> 
     <property name="returnCode" value="99"/>
     <target name="RUN-MYCLASS">            
          <java classname="my.company.class" fork="true" resultproperty="build.rc" failonerror="false">
                <arg value="${workdir}"/>
                <classpath>
                     <pathelement path="${java.class.path}"/>
                </classpath>
          </java>   
      </target> 
</project>
```

**myJunitTest.java**

```
public class TestAntScripts extends TestCase {

public void testMyAnt() throws IOException {

    File dir = new File("pathToSpecific.xml");

    Project p = null;
    try {
        File buildFile = new File(buildFileName);
        p = new Project();
        DefaultLogger consoleLogger = new DefaultLogger();
        consoleLogger.setErrorPrintStream(System.err);
        consoleLogger.setOutputPrintStream(System.out);
        consoleLogger.setMessageOutputLevel(Project.MSG_INFO);
        p.addBuildListener(consoleLogger);
        p.addBuildListener(new CustomBuildListener(this));
        p.fireBuildStarted();
        p.init();
        ProjectHelper helper = ProjectHelper.getProjectHelper();
        p.addReference("ant.projectHelper", helper);
        helper.parse(p, buildFile);
        p.fireBuildFinished(null);
    } catch (BuildException e) {
        p.fireBuildFinished(e);
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.err.println("AntRunner for buildfile " + buildFileName
                + " failed with Exception ");
    }

    String rc = p.getProperty("returnCode");
    assertEquals(0, Integer.parseInt(rc));

    }


public void taskFinished(String buildRc) {
    assertEquals(0, buildRc);   
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**

how's the approach to assign a value to a already defined property? defined a var returnCode outside the java-target and try to assign the value like `<var name="returnCode" value="${build.rc}"/>` inside the target. not runnin'..

**EDIT2:**
added a custom BuildListener and grabbing the build.rc over there.

```
  @Override
  public void targetFinished(BuildEvent event) {

    if (event.getTarget().getName().trim().equalsIgnoreCase("RUN-MYCLASS")) {
        String buildRc = event.getTarget().getProject().getProperty("build.rc");    
        tester.taskFinished(buildRc, jobname);
    }
```

tester is my JUnit-Test, which will be set in Constructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

added a custom BuildListener and grabbing the build.rc over there.

```
@Override
public void targetFinished(BuildEvent event) {

if (event.getTarget().getName().trim().equalsIgnoreCase("RUN-MYCLASS")) {
    String buildRc = event.getTarget().getProject().getProperty("build.rc");    
    tester.setReturnCode(buildRc);
}
```

and then testing like

```
assertEquals(0, Integer.parseInt(this.returnCode));
```

Answer (score 0):

The [ant manual mentions that](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/local.html)

> Property scopes exist at Apache Ant's various "block" levels. These include targets as well as the Parallel and Sequential task containers (including Macrodef bodies).

Pretty sure that `build.rc` is *local* and only valid in the target scope. So we can't access it after the target has been executed.

Try to define a global property (with the `<property>` element) and assign the result code from the java task to that property.

Comment: ain'get macrodef neither unset running :( can you post any complete code of the according file? (general.xml or specific.xml..)